# Google Places API: Convert Place IDs to Place Name

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-sheets, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I've managed to generate a list of place IDs and their respective links using the following code from https://www.labnol.org/google-maps-sheets-200817.

```js
/\*\*

* @fileoverview Provides custom Geo functions in Google Sheets for matching boundaries.
* * SearchRegionByLocation searches for a region whose boundary contains the specified latitude/longitude coordinates.
* * SearchRegionByAddress searches for a region whose boundary contains the specified address.
* * SearchRegionByPlaceId searches for a region whose boundary contains the specified place ID.
* * LookupRegionByName looks up a region with the specified name.
* * LookupRegionByUnitCode looks up a region with the specified unit code.
* @OnlyCurrentDoc
  \*/

var api_key = "API_KEY"; // An unrestricted key is recommended for local use only (deployment is NOT recommended).

function format_url(place_id) {
return place_id && 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=%20&query_place_id=' + place_id;
}

function format_result(result) {
let matches = result.matches || \[\];
let firstMatch = result.matches\[0\] || {};

let placeId = firstMatch.matchedPlaceId || '';
let debugInfo = firstMatch.debugInfo || '';
let candidates = firstMatch.candidatePlaceIds || \[\];

return \[\[
placeId || '(NULL)',
format_url(placeId),
debugInfo,
candidates\[0\],
format_url(candidates\[0\]),
candidates\[1\],
format_url(candidates\[1\]),
candidates\[2\],
format_url(candidates\[2\])
\]\];
}

}
/\*\*

* Looks up a place with the specified name.
* 
* @param {string} place_name - The name of the place (e.g., "Palo Alto").
* @param {string} place_type - The geo type id of the place (e.g., "locality").
* @param {string} \[region_code='us'\] - The region code of the place (e.g., "US").
* @param {string} \[language_code='en'\] - The language code of the place's name. (e.g., "en").
* 
* @return {string} The place_id of the place, or null if none was found.
* 
* @customfunction
  \*/
  function LookupRegionByName(
  place, place_type, region_code, language_code) {
  var data = {
  "identifiers": \[ {
  "place": '' + place,
  "place_type": place_type,
  "region_code": region_code || 'us',
  "language_code": language_code || 'en',
  }
  \]
  };

var options = {
'method' : 'post',
'contentType': 'application/json',
'headers': {
'X-Goog-Api-Key' : api_key
},
// Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
'payload' : JSON.stringify(data),
//'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
'https://regionlookup.googleapis.com/v1alpha:lookupRegion',
options);

var resultText = response.getContentText();

console.log(resultText);
var result = JSON.parse(resultText);

return format_result(result);
}
\`
```

However instead of the output being either a Place ID or a link to the city (which uses a PlaceID )I simply want the name of the place in a cell so I can then have a database to import into excel etc.

I.e. instead of an ID and a link to 'London', I just want the cell to say 'London'.

I tried to search for a Place ID to Place Name formula but to no avail.

Comment: The reason for that is because you can only cache Place_IDs and coordinates taken from Google Maps API and for only a certain period of time. Trying to cache other data from them would be against the Terms of Service as per https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms/

Comment: Not quite sure that is the problem. I just want to obtain literal text data for the location instead of a link to the location on Google maps.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing statement. It is possible to just geocode the place ID to convert it to an address. But what I was trying to state on previous comment that although it is possible, you have to be careful on your implementation because from what I know, storing address names would be against their ToS.